# Split elements of a dataframe into sub-columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so :

```
| -1W             | ME            | QE              | YE               |
|-----------------|---------------|-----------------|------------------|
| [119.06, 1.20]  | [120.27, 0.0] | [125.85, -5.58] | [80.53, 39.73]   |
| [207.00, 3.70]  | [210.71, 0.0] | [215.54, -4.83] | [119.74, 90.97]  |
| [313.32, 8.28]  | [321.61, 0.0] | [325.20, -3.59] | [203.13, 118.47] |
| [517.90, 10.87] | [528.77, 0.0] | [510.14, 18.63] | [395.14, 133.63] |
```

How could I separate the elements within this dataframe into two sub-column headers - one header for each element per column (kind of like a multi-indexed Dataframe)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
   
d =[[ [119.06, 1.20]  , [120.27, 0.0] , [125.85, -5.58] , [80.53, 39.73] ],  
 [[207.00, 3.70]  , [210.71, 0.0] , [215.54, -4.83] , [119.74, 90.97]  ],
 [[313.32, 8.28]  , [321.61, 0.0] , [325.20, -3.59] , [203.13, 118.47] ],
 [[517.90, 10.87] , [528.77, 0.0] , [510.14, 18.63] , [395.14, 133.63]]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['-1W','ME', 'QE', 'YE'])
dfe = df.explode(df.columns.tolist())
    
df_out = dfe.set_index(dfe.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True).unstack()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
      -1W             ME           QE             YE        
        0      1       0    1       0      1       0       1
0  119.06    1.2  120.27  0.0  125.85  -5.58   80.53   39.73
1   207.0    3.7  210.71  0.0  215.54  -4.83  119.74   90.97
2  313.32   8.28  321.61  0.0   325.2  -3.59  203.13  118.47
3   517.9  10.87  528.77  0.0  510.14  18.63  395.14  133.63
```

---

To rename level=1 of pd.MultiIndex dataframe header,

```
df_out = dfe.set_index(dfe.groupby(level=0).cumcount().map({0:'high', 1:'low'}), 
                       append=True).unstack()
```

Output:

```
      -1W             ME           QE             YE        
     high    low    high  low    high    low    high     low
0  119.06    1.2  120.27  0.0  125.85  -5.58   80.53   39.73
1   207.0    3.7  210.71  0.0  215.54  -4.83  119.74   90.97
2  313.32   8.28  321.61  0.0   325.2  -3.59  203.13  118.47
3   517.9  10.87  528.77  0.0  510.14  18.63  395.14  133.63
```

Comment: this is really helpful. Thank you! But is it possible to rename the new levels of this dataframe?

Comment: I also intend to join/concatenate this dataframe after it's been stacked with another dataframe that has the standard levels (not stacked). How would you join/concatenate these two dataframes?

Answer (score 2):

Lets do `stack` and `unstack` to reshape dataframe:

```
s = df.stack()
pd.DataFrame([*s], s.index).stack().unstack([1, 2])
```

---

```
      -1W             ME           QE             YE        
        0      1       0    1       0      1       0       1
0  119.06   1.20  120.27  0.0  125.85  -5.58   80.53   39.73
1  207.00   3.70  210.71  0.0  215.54  -4.83  119.74   90.97
2  313.32   8.28  321.61  0.0  325.20  -3.59  203.13  118.47
3  517.90  10.87  528.77  0.0  510.14  18.63  395.14  133.63
```

Comment: wow, tysm! But is it possible to rename the levels of this new dataframe @Shubham Sharma?

Comment: You can specify the name in the dataframe initializer itself, check: `pd.DataFrame([*s], s.index, columns=['foo', 'bar']).stack().unstack([1, 2])`

Comment: Thank you! That worked really well for this dataset. I also intend to join/concatenate this dataframe after it's been stacked with another dataframe that has the standard levels (not stacked). How would you join/concatenate these two dataframes?

Comment: @ho0sh12 I think in that case a simple join would work for e.g `other_df.join(pd.DataFrame([*s], s.index, columns=['foo', 'bar']).stack().unstack([1, 2]))` but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing your other dataframe so I would advise asking a new question :-)

Comment: sadly, that join produces a dataframe that only has 1 column index. It make each sub-column into it's own column (i.e. (-1W, OAS to Treasury (bp)) (-1W, Change in OAS to Today (bp)) (ME, OAS to Treasury (bp)) (ME, Change in OAS to Today (bp))).